# Drupal Admin form AJAX callback not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-ajax

I am trying to implement an AJAX callback to change a drop down list options based on the values of another drop down.I have looked into the examples online and the examples in the examples module. I am trying to implement the example on one of the admin pages forms.

To simplify, I tried to achieve the following: Just to change the title of the second dropdown with a random number once the first dropdown has changed. Please note that I am using a field collection field.

```
function myaction_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

$form['field_programme_permission']['und']['0']['field_programme']['und']['#ajax']=array(
        'event' => 'change',
        'callback' => 'programmes_ajax_callback',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'wrapper' => 'countries_wrapper'
      );


$form['field_programme_permission']['und']['0']['field_countries']['und']['#title']=rand(1,100);
return $form;
}

function programmes_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {    
 return $form['field_programme_permission']['und']['0']['field_countries'];
}
```

It is as if programmes_ajax_callback is not triggered at all. I see this Drupal AJAX please wait message but nothing actually happens. The weird thing, If I submit the form and it doesn't pass validation, I don't even see this Drupal AJAX "please wait" message. I have simplified the code as much as possible to try to pin point the problem, but it didn't work...

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get an error? Try to error_log('something') in your callback to make sure that you don't even get there.

Comment: Try returning a simple string instead of the $form array. return '<div>Test</div>' in the callback. BTW do you use debugger?

Comment: Does `countries_wrapper` actually exists on the page? Possible issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the fact that countries_wrapper didn't actually exist as I was actually calling it countries-wrapper somewhere else.

Find below the code that I have actually used. This code covers a muti-value (up to 10) field collection at which one field (countries) in the field collection is dependent on the other (programme). Hopefully, it will prove to be useful for someone.

```
    function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

          for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
          if(($form_id=='user_register_form') || ($form_id=='user_profile_form')) {

              if(isset($form_state['values']['field_programme_permission'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['field_programme'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'])) {
                $programme_selected= $form_state['values']['field_programme_permission'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['field_programme'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'];
              } else {
                $programme_selected=0;
              }

              if(isset($form_state['field']['field_programme_permission']['und']['entity'][$i]->field_programme['und'][0]['tid'])){
                 $programme_selected=$form_state['field']['field_programme_permission']['und']['entity'][$i]->field_programme['und'][0]['tid'];
              }

          $form['field_programme_permission'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['field_programme'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#ajax']=array(
            'event' => 'change',
            'callback' => '_programmes_ajax_callback',
            'method' => 'replace',
            'wrapper' => 'countries_wrapper'.$i
          );
          $form['field_programme_permission'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['field_countries'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#title']='Countries';

          $form['field_programme_permission'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['field_countries'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#prefix']='<div id="countries_wrapper'.$i.'">';
          $form['field_programme_permission'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['field_countries'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#suffix']='</div>';
          $form['field_programme_permission'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['field_countries'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options']=_countries_ajax_callback($programme_selected);

        }
        } 
return $form;
}

function _programmes_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
//we first need to know the triggering element, to know the index of the countries field that we need to affect.
$index= $form_state['triggering_element']['#field_parents'][2];
return $form['field_programme_permission'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$index]['field_countries'];
}

function _countries_ajax_callback($selected) {

  $programme_value = $selected;
  $options=array();
  if(taxonomy_term_load($programme_value)){
  $programme_taxonomy=taxonomy_term_load($programme_value);
  if(isset($programme_taxonomy->field_countries[LANGUAGE_NONE])) {
  $countries=$programme_taxonomy->field_countries[LANGUAGE_NONE];
  foreach($countries as $country) {
    $country_tid = $country['tid'];
    $country_term = taxonomy_term_load($country_tid);
    $country_name = $country_term->name;
    $options[$country_tid]=$country_name;
  }
  }
  }
  return $options;
}
```